# Mergesort for linked list

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I have a source code of Mergesort for a unordered linked list as followed. Suppose that I've already done the `merge` function and `z` is the sentinel key.

```
node *mergesort(node *c)
{
    node *a, *b;
    if (c->next != z)
    {
        a = c;
        b = c->next->next->next;
        while (b != z)
        {
            c = c->next;
            b = b->next->next;
        }
        b = c->next;
        c->next = c;
        return merge(mergesort(a), mergesort(b));
    }
    return c;
}
```

I have 3 suspisions about this implementation:

1. As you can see that `b` point to the third element of the linked list. I don't know why because I think that it just need to be `b = c->next` is enough.
2. In the loop `while` it also have `b = b->next->next`, as I understand, it continues to point to the fourth element after `c` in that array. Is it ok if I write `b = b->next`?
3. As I understand the algorithm of `mergesort`, it divides the array into two subarray `a` and `b` and then mergesort each subarray recursively, but I just see that it only work with the array `b`. Is there anything wrong with this implementation?

Comment: It looks like the intent was to split the list by holding the head in `a` and then advancing `c` to the halfway point by having another pointer `b` going twice as fast and then stopping the `c` advancement when `b` reached the end. There's confusion on how ends are marked though. Half the code seems to think it's using a special `z`, and half seems to think it's using a self link (as shown by `c->next = c`) to indicate the end.

Comment: @bg2b That is what I feel really confused. I think that there maybe something wrong here but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in this code:

- `b = c->next->next->next;` has undefined behavior if `c->next->next` is null
- `b = b->next->next;` has undefined behavior if `b->next` is null
- the list is not properly split before `b`, furthermore `c->next = c;` creates a loop which will cause the algorithm to fail with an infinite loop.

The function needs substantial changes to fix these problems.

Here is a modified version:

```c
node *mergesort(node *c) {
    node *a, *b;
    /* test if list has at least 2 elements */
    if (c != z && c->next != z) {
        /* locate the middle node */
        a = b = c;
        while (b->next != z && b->next->next != z) {
            c = c->next;
            b = b->next->next;
        }
        /* split the list between c and c->next */
        b = c->next;
        c->next = z;
        /* sort both sublists and merge them */
        return merge(mergesort(a), mergesort(b));
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Yep, I think that my opinion is right, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: How about the last question?

Comment: @chqrlie isn't this simply a segmentation fault situation for trying to access NULL pointer?

Comment: @sergeyrar: a a segmentation fault is a friendly form of undefined behavior. The debugger will point the programmer to the problem immediately. Some systems do not crash on null pointer dereferencing, which makes it much harder to debug.

Comment: So how do I fix this source  code to operate properly?

Comment: @HoangNam: see the modified version

Comment: @chqrlie I think that there are 2 problem:

1. I think the initialization step after ``if`` must be ``a=c; b = c->next``

2. There is a problem that ``a`` doesn't move through the partition step. I think that there must be a line ``a = c`` at the end instead

Comment: @HoangNam: not necessarily: initializing `b` as `a` or `a->next` changes the spot where the list is split by 1 position: a 3 element list will be split as 1+2 or 2+1.

Comment: @chqrlie you means ``initializing b as c or c->next`` right??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207491/discussion-between-hoang-nam-and-chqrlie).